# Custom QWidget Not Showing in QMainWindow (Qt4.8)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

**Summary:  I wish to use X11 to paint a custom QWidget.  It works unless that widget is in a layout or QMainWindow**

I have a custom widget derived from QWidget that I'd like to be the main widget in a QMainWindow.  When I run something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    ModelWidget mw;
    mw.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

everything works fine, including resizing, obscuring and revealing the window contents, etc.

However, if I try to use that widget as the central widget in a QMainWindow, nothing is painted in the central widget area of the QMainWindow.

Here's the constructor of the QMainWindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    modelwidg = new ModelWidget;
    setCentralWidget(modelwidg);
    createActions();
    createMenus();
}
```

I get the feeling that there's something related to the size or resize policy of my custom widget that I need to implement, but I can't find any documentation regarding what functions must be provided by a widget for it to be usable as a central widget in a QMainWindow.  What am I missing?

*Edit:  Here's the custom widget*

```
ModelWidget::ModelWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow);
    setAutoFillBackground(true);

    const QX11Info &info = x11Info();

    // Elided X11 and glX specific stuff
    create(wnd, true, true);
}

void ModelWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    // scene.render is just some OpenGL stuff
    scene->render();
    glXSwapBuffers(dpy, glxwnd);
}

void ModelWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * e)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, e->size().width(), e->size().height());
    scene->set_aspect(float(e->size().width()) / float(e->size().height()));
    update();
}

QSize ModelWidget::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(640, 480);
}
```

*Further...*

According to the docs,

> To render outside of Qt's paint system, e.g., if you require native
>   painting primitives, you need to reimplement QWidget::paintEngine() to
>   return 0 and set [Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen].

I've done that, but the window still remains unpainted.  I suspect that one of my X11 objects, `Window`, `Display*`, is being altered by adding this widget to a layout or MainWindow.

Comment: If you suspect that something is wrong with your custom widget why don't you then post the code of it?

Comment: @user2672165: Done.  I didn't add the code at first because the widget works fine if it's the only widget in the app.  It's only when I call setCentralWidget with it that it doesn't display.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I should be quiet because I haven't got a clue what effect all those Qt::WA_.. attributes have. The only advice I can give is that I would test to disable them and see if one of them is causing trouble.